# fatal error: 'Python/Python.h' file not found while installing couchapp

Tags: python, macos, couchapp

I am trying to install **couchapp** from the terminal on **macOs High Sierra**.

I have **python 2.7.10** installed (by default) and I run `$ pip2 install couchapp` according to the couchapp documentation.

This is the error I get:

```
src/watchdog_fsevents.c:22:10: fatal error: 'Python/Python.h' file not found
    #include <Python/Python.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

 ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for watchdog
```

Here is what I have when I do `$ ls` in **/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/**

- Examples
- Modules
- Python
- Resources
- Versions
- module.map

---

What I have tried so far:

1. Check that Xcode CL Tools are already installed running `$ xcode-select --install`
2. Try to use pip3 instead of pip2 (I have installed python 3.6 with Homebrew), but I get the same error message.

Do you have any idea? I have read other posts but they did not solve my problem.

Thank you

Comment: What this generally always means is that you don't have Python development headers present.

Comment: Closely related to [What did Apple do to the Python framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151548/what-did-apple-do-to-the-python-framework)

Comment: Install `python-dev` if not installed. Hopefully helps.

Comment: @SumitJha, there is no `python-dev` package for MacOS. Rather, there, these headers are included with XCode.

Comment: Ah yes. Then add `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/` to `$PATH` and maybe `brew reinstall python` could help.

Comment: Hello @SumitJha, I have tried to add/reinstall but it didn't work.
I also tried to update Xcode but it is already up to date.

Comment: @Sala . ` 'Python/Python.h' file not found` typically means the compiler is not able to find the path. Do you know where your Python.h exist? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778495/fatal-error-python-h-file-not-found-while-installing-opencv/35778751) might be helpful.

Comment: @SumitJha the path is `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/` ... Maybe that's Python3 doing the mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a very similar problem on my High Sierra (10.13.5) setup with Xcode CLI tools installed; for me the Python.h was found in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7`

(Some resources say the location can be found via `find /usr/local/Cellar/ -name Python.h`, however this seems not work if your python was not installed with brew.)

Add the location to your C include path, or at compile time as a flag by setting -I flag as such: `-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7`.

The part that tripped me up was the import statement should then look like: `#include <Python.h>` rather than `#include <Python/Python.h>` if your Python.h is directly in the `python2.7` directory.

Hope that helps,